# Is it safe to rename the Default Web Site in IIS 7.5?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, microsoft-web-deploy

I am having a problem deploying to Default Web Site using web deploy.  The problem is similar to this: [MSDeploy batch file does not handle quotes anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539968/msdeploy-batch-file-does-not-handle-quotes-anymore) where web deploy is choking on deployment paths with spaces.

The easiest way to solve it would be to rename Default Web Site to something else without spaces.   Is it safe to rename Default Web Site? Will it cause any side effects?

Comment: Why dont you create a new website and associate the port 80 to http. But you need to have your Default Web Site stopped as a single port can be associated with only one website to listen. You would not bother about renaming and the consequences.

Comment: All the virtual directories etc are already setup under Default Web Site.  It would take some time to recreate all of that under a new website.  Rename on the other hand would only take a few seconds.

Comment: I have done this with no ill-effect.

Comment: Most people don't run around with a project called "Default Web Site" clearly this can be changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I tried it and the answer is Yes - you can rename the Default Web Site without any side effects.

You do need to recycle the application afterwards, and then everything will operate as before.

Any script that refers to Default Web Site (eg web deploy) needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful in diagnosing problems I experienced after a site was renamed.

Comment: +1 for the: recycle the application pool afterwards. This was solving the error after renaming a website.