# MS deploy from deploy dialog (not powershell) does not work if there are quotes

Tags: c#, iis, msdeploy, visual-studio-2010

In my Visual Studio 2010 SP1Rel, MS web deploy has suddenly stopped workingwith this error:

```
Unrecognized argument 'Web'. All arguments must begin with "-".
```

The argument "Web" refers to the parameter "Default Web Site", ie web deploy cannot deploy if the path contains spaces.  This worked until today.

If I rename my website to DefaultWebSite (no spaces) then the error message changes to:

```
Unrecognized argument 'Source=10.10.10.1\MSSQLSERVER,1432;Initial'. 
All arguments must begin with "-".
```

There are other questions about the same error but the circumstances are different.  I am using the built in web deploy dialog.

Same error, but for a batch script: [MSDeploy batch file does not handle quotes anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539968/msdeploy-batch-file-does-not-handle-quotes-anymore)
Same error, but in powershell: [How do you call msdeploy from powershell when the parameters have spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499699/how-do-you-call-msdeploy-from-powershell-when-the-parameters-have-spaces)

These questions are related to installing VS 2010 SP1.  I did not install SP1.  It might have been automatically installed in a windows update.

How do I solve this error when using the MS deploy dialog (right click the project in VS and click Deploy)?

Comment: Do you have <UseMSDeployExe>True</...> in your project file or projectName.wpp.targets file?

Comment: Yes I have UseMSDeployExe = true in the wpp.targets file

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the way the UseMSDeployExe flag works; it's generating an invalid set of command line parameters for WebDeploy.  Try removing that line from your wpp.targets file, and it should work correctly.  This bug will be fixed in a future release.

Side note: UseMSDeployExe is mainly intended as a test hook for the VS team to debug issues with WebDeploy.  VS has 2 separate modes: In-proc usage of WebDeploy (via reflection I think), and Out-of-proc by shelling out to msdeploy.exe (hence the UseMSDeployExe flag).  There's no real benefit to setting UseMSDeployExe, unless you're looking for the command arguments VS is passing to WebDeploy.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.  I don't remember why that flag was true, probably due to some earlier problems we had with msdeploy.  Its the only flag in my wpp.targets, so I might just remove the whole file.